# Is there any built in method/gem to convert string into English sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any ruby method to convert string into sentence.

Like `this is a sentence` to `This is a sentence.`

or

`i m happy` to `I'm happy`

Comment: @Andrew, such answers are not useful without argument.

Comment: @CarySwoveland picky mode on? :) What argument do you expect to see here besides “because it is not»?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [gingerice](https://github.com/subosito/gingerice) gem that might apt for my question.

BTW thank you all for having time for me.

Its working as expected for me.
[image: output]

Regards,
Sreeraj

Comment: Any third party gem obviously can’t apt for your question, since the question clearly stated “any ruby method.” Downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
a="this is a sentence"

puts a.capitalize
```

output

```
This is a sentence
```

Comment: I know  capitalize works in this case. how about "i m happy" => "I'm happy."

Comment: @sreerajnyros modify your requirements in your post and try to add all cases

Comment: There is no such method to convert some line into meaningful English lines.

Comment: @PavneetSingh The way he has been asking questions seems to be he wants to convert a English lines into meaningful English lines, but there is no such method, that's Andrew Li said 'No there is not'

Comment: yeah the previous example was misleading

Comment: I have marked it as "to English Sentence" in question how could one think capitalization could solve it.

Comment: Everything has a way out. Don't ever under estimate any language. We just might not ware of the complete language. BTW thank you for having some time for me.